# How much contributions should I give?

Tags: discussion

I was banned from questioning a long time ago. Till now I have gained a lot of reputation points. According to help center 'The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive
contributions outweigh those questions whicha
were poorly received.' But how much contributions should I give?

Comment: related [Question ban – what exactly are “positive contributions”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224001/201151) : *As Robert Harvey pointed out, the exact algorithm for lifting the ban is secret. The gist, however, is to make contributions that help the community. In other words: try to make yourself helpful to others.*